# Variable assignment inside an 'if' condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators

How does the below code execute?

```
if(a=2 && (b=8))
{
    console.log(a)
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a=8
```

Comment: Why would you put `b=8` in parens but not `a=2`? It looks almost as if this is a trolling attempt.

Comment: When you saw `b=`, why didn't you bother to check the value of `b`? That would have given enough clues...

Comment: @NiklasB. If I don't put b=8 into brackets then it gives me an error because it executes it someting like a = (2 && b=8). I am not clear about this error but the reason to put b=8 into brackets is only give high precedence to `b=8` or you can simply say, to avoid error.

Comment: @Jay So you already knew that the code parses as `a = (2 && (b=8))`. This pretty much would have allowed to figure out the problem. At the very least I'd expect a minimal amount of debugging before posting a question on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the `if` statement, but:

```
if(a=2 && (b=8))
```

Here the last one, `(b=8)`, actually returns 8 as assigning always returns the assigned value, so it's the same as writing

```
a = 2 && 8;
```

And `2 && 8` returns `8`, as 2 is truthy, so it's the same as writing `a = 8`.

Comment: _With_ the side effect that b will also be 8, of course.

Comment: @CompuChip - Yep, the assigment assigns `8` to `b`, but assigning will return the assigned value as well, so that's correct.

Comment: "assigning always returns the assigned value" - didn't know this one, thank you.

Answer (score 19):

It's generally a bad idea to do variable assignment inside of an `if` statement like that. However, in this particular case you're essentially doing this:

```
if(a = (2 && (b = 8)));
```

The `(b = 8)` part returns `8`, so we can rewrite it as:

```
if(a = (2 && 8))
```

The `&&` operator returns the value of the right hand side if the left hand side is considered true, so `2 && 8` returns `8`, so we can rewrite again as:

```
if(a = 8)
```

Comment: is it because anything greater than 0 is considered true?

Comment: @staticx Any non-zero integer (so positive *or* negative) is considered true when converted to a boolean.

Answer (score 8):

It is called **operator precedence**

```
(a=2 && (b=8))
```

In the **above example**. then results are evaluated against the main && sign.

```
(a=2 && (b=8)) evaluated to a = 2 && 8
```

So **2 && 8** return **a = 8**

Answer (score 5):

You're setting (not comparing) `a` to `2 && (b=8)`. Since `2` is tru-ish the second half of the expression will be executed, i.e. `a = true && (b = 8)`, i.e. `a = (b = 8)`, i.e. `a = 8`.

Answer (score 5):

Your statement is interpreted like

```
a = (2 && (b=8))
```

when you uses `&&` statement, then last true statement value will be returned. Here (b=8) will becomes value `8` which is true and last statement.

Answer (score 4):

To understand what is going on, refer to the [operator precedence and associativity chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). The expression **`a = 2 && (b = 8)`** is evaluated as follows:

- `&&` operator is evaluated before `=` since it has higher priority

  - the left hand expression `2` is evaluated which is truthy
  - the right hand expression `b = 8` is evaluated (`b` becomes `8` and `8` is returned)
  - `8` is returned
- `a = 8` is evaluated (`a` becomes `8` and `8` is returned)

Finally, the `if` clause is tested for `8`.

Note that `2` does not play any role in this example. However, if we use some falsy value then the result will be entirely different. In that case `a` will contain that falsy value and `b` will remain untouched.

Comment: What makes `2` truthy?